# Wrong Output for Array Operations Using GPU

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, numba

I'm trying to write a function that performs element-wise addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division on 2d arrays using Anaconda Accelerate, but the function I wrote keeps getting the wrong answer. Not sure what's going on.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

#Define functions
ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV = 1, 2, 3, 4
@cuda.jit('void(complex64[:,:], complex64[:,:], int8)')
def math_inplace_2d_cuda(a, b, operation):
    m, n = a.shape[0], a.shape[1]
    i, j = cuda.grid(2)
    if i < m and j < n:
        if operation == ADD: a[i, j] += b[i, j]
        if operation == SUB: a[i, j] -= b[i, j]
        if operation == MUL: a[i, j] *= b[i, j]
        if operation == DIV: a[i, j] /= b[i, j]

def math_inplace_2d_host(a, b, operation):
    m, n = a.shape[0], a.shape[1]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if operation == ADD: a[i, j] += b[i, j]
            if operation == SUB: a[i, j] -= b[i, j]
            if operation == MUL: a[i, j] *= b[i, j]
            if operation == DIV: a[i, j] /= b[i, j]

#Create arrays
a = np.array([[1., 2], [3, 4]])
b = a.copy()*2

a_dev = cuda.to_device(a)
b_dev = cuda.to_device(b)

#Threading
threadperblock = 32, 8
def best_grid_size(size, tpb):
    bpg = np.ceil(np.array(size, dtype=np.float) / tpb).astype(np.int).tolist()
    return tuple(bpg)
blockpergrid = best_grid_size(a_dev.shape, threadperblock)
stream = cuda.stream()

#Do operation
op = ADD
math_inplace_2d_host(a, b, op)
math_inplace_2d_cuda[blockpergrid, threadperblock, stream](a_dev, b_dev, op)
print '\nhost\n', a
print '\ndevice\n', a_dev.copy_to_host()
```

This program, with the provided values for the a and b arrays, results in this output (the host and device arrays should be the same):

```
host
[[  3.   6.]
 [  9.  12.]]

device
[[  384.   768.]
 [ 1024.  1536.]]
```

When I try subtracting, I get this:

```
host
[[-1. -2.]
 [-3. -4.]]

device
[[ -4.65661287e-10  -1.19209290e-07]
 [ -1.19209290e-07  -1.19209290e-07]]
```

For multiplication:

```
host
[[  2.   8.]
 [ 18.  32.]]

device
[[  1.59512330e-314   1.59615943e-314]
 [  1.59672607e-314   1.59732508e-314]]
```

For division:

```
host
[[ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]]

device
[[  5.25836359e-315   5.25433420e-315]
 [  5.25481893e-315   5.25525520e-315]]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "keeps getting the wrong answer"? Do you mean that it's numerically incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it's numerically incorrect. I included the output in the question. The array under 'device' should be equal to the array under 'host'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me if I change the `jit` signature to:

```
@cuda.jit('void(float64[:,:], float64[:,:], int64)')
```

or if I change the definition of `a` and `op` to:

```
a = np.array([[1., 2], [3, 4]]).astype(np.complex64)
...
op = np.int8(ADD)
```

In the latter case, where the op is `ADD`, I get:

```
host
[[  3.+0.j   6.+0.j]
 [  9.+0.j  12.+0.j]]

device
[[  3.+0.j   6.+0.j]
 [  9.+0.j  12.+0.j]]
```

I would have expected a type error emitted from Numba, but it seems to silently cast and do something wrong. Maybe raise the issue on the Numba google group.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.